# Laravel 5.1 - How to get updates to relationships in static::updating event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to create a trait (for models) that would automatically write all changes made to the model in 'adjustments' table. It would save changes in before and after jsons.

This is the code so far (from [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/eloquent-techniques/episodes/2)):

```
trait LoggingTrait
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::updating(function($action){
            $action->adjustments()->create(
            [
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'before' => json_encode(array_intersect_key($action->getOriginal(), $action->getDirty())),
                'after' => json_encode($action->getDirty())
            ]);
        });
    }

    public function adjustments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Adjustment::class, 'adjustable');
    }
}
```

This is working very well, except it doesn't save changes to related models.

To make it more clear, this is my Action model:

```
class Action extends Model
{
    use LoggingTrait;

    public function actionTypes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ActionType::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function spreadingMaterial()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SpreadingMaterial::class);
    }
}
```

The trait logs all the changes made to the actual Action model, but doesn't care for the changes made to the $action->users(), $action->spreadingMaterials() and $action->actionTypes(). How would I get these changes within the static::updating(...) event?

Or if that is not possible, any other idea on how to tackle this problem is more than welcome.

Comment: Just use the LoggingTrait inside the ActionType, User and SpreadingMaterial classes and it will fire when they get changed by the updates.

Comment: This wouldn't work, because then changes about the same model (Action)  would be written in different rows. I want all the changes to the Action and its related models in a single database row.

Comment: You could get the data from the relations with the `relationsToArray()` method and merge it the model data